# how to redirect the page but stay on the same localhost

Tags: html, url, redirect

My Requirement: I am trying to render an image as the background of the screen when I press a certain button. But I don't want the url to redirect, instead I wont like an image to render. However I want the image to have an image map on it, so maybe I would like an HTML to render? Is that possible

Specifics: This runs on a localhost

Questions:
How do I do this? 
What tools do I look into?

Comment: Javascript is a common way to do such things.

Comment: I've looked into that, such as replacing the body tag, but it's not working I guess is it possible to render a HTML without redirecting?

Comment: You can do almost anything using javascript without redirecting. 
But you need to learn some basics about HTML/DOM/JS first.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to show a webpage in a webpage? Do you want to set the background image on a click? Do you want an image to be clickable?

Comment: preferably, a different html in one click but i dont want the browser to change